# Linking Test cases in test manager

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I have some automated test cases which I execute using MTM 2012, I want to link these test cases in such a way that when I execute the first test case all are executed one by one sequentially. I do not want to execute all test cases one by one; they should get executed when I run the first test case.

Can this be done?

I have tried linking of test cases but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to create a *Test Suite* containing your *Test Cases* you want to run in a bunch.

Now you can run this *Test Suite* (right click on it and select "Run" of "Run with options").

Note that only *Test Cases* belonging to this *Test Suite* will run, that means if this *Test Suite* contains another nested *Test Suites* the *Test Cases* belonging to the nested *Test Suites* will not run.

**Be aware**: the order the *Test Cases* are running in is undefined.

Comment: we can order them by clicking on 'Order' in test plan which is just beside 'Configurations' and number them!

Comment: No, unfortunately this order does not apply when running **automated** *Test Cases*, see [tests execution on MTM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d79e4afc-50a1-44cb-8624-4d0f4d2800b3/tests-execution-on-mtm). The only way to achieve that is creating *Ordered Test* in Visual Studio and automate your *Test Case* by this *Ordered Test*.